# Node.js: Request + Cheerio, website is unresponsive

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I've been trying to scrape this url unsuccessfully and retrieve the "Date of Organization in Massachusetts."  I suspect I might just be mislabeling the DOM, but have already tried a series of ids and classes.  Any suggestions - I'm using cheerio and request.

```
var url = 'http://corp.sec.state.ma.us/CorpWeb/CorpSearch/CorpSummary.aspx?FEIN=800829800&SEARCH_TYPE=1';
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
if (err)
    throw err;
$ = cheerio.load(body);
var orgdate = $('#MainContent_tblOrg .p1 td #MainContent_lblOrganisationDate').text();
console.log(orgdate);
```

});

Comment: Your code gives me "08-20-2013" as expected... By the way you can use just  `#MainContent_lblOrganisationDate`...

Comment: Hm..I guess I'm a bit stumped because I still am outputting a blank.  I'm calling it on my terminal as node masos_node.js (name of file) and also doing the request commands: var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio'); - what could be resulting in a blank output?

Comment: I'm also getting a cookie notice, I'm not sure if this is what is preventing me from scraping the website.  But then also not sure why gangabass was able to successfully extract the information.  document.cookie = "TS6025d1_75=" + "74e3111fa5e3d57280427993fd11fcd4:" + chlg + ":" + slt + ":" + crc + ";Max-Age=3600;path=/";